# How to make my buttons fit my navbar size

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm new to the web design world, so I was playing a bit with bootstrap's and w3 help and I encountered the following issue.
I've got this right now:
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae4qz.png)

and I want to make the two buttons on the right to fit the whole navigation bar height, is there a way to do that? something like a match_parent in android.
Here's my code:

```css
li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
li a {
    width: 80px;
    height: match-parent;
    background-color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 24px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
li a:hover {
    background: #1075e9;
    /*border-radius: 50px;*/
    border-color: #1075e9;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
li a:active{
    background-color: #07274d;
    border-color: #07274d;
    transition: 0s;
}

.right-li{
    float: right !important;
}
.navbar {
    list-style: none;
    background: rgb(49, 48, 48);
    height: 115.8px;
}
#banner-img{
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 105.8px;
    padding: 4px; 
}
#banner-img:hover{
    background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#banner-img:active{
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    border-color: white;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mi-archivo-css.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test page</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>


    
    <header>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li>
                    <img src="logo.png" id="banner-img" href="#home">
                </li>
                <li class="right-li">
                    <a href="#me">Me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="right-li">
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </header>

    <body>    
        <!-- page content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Height for li as 100% and remove the top and bottom padding from a. Use **line height** to vertically align the text.

```
li {
        display: inline;
        height:100%;/* made the height to be the same as the parent's height */
        float: left;
        }

li a {
            line-height:110px; /* line height should be the same as the element's height*/
            width: 80px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
            font-family: Arial;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 0 24px; /* removed the padding from top and bottom to prevent the a element overflowing*/   
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        }
```

EDIT. Oh and if you use Chrome, Firefox , they have developer tools which you can use to see what elements to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` and `flex-grow: 1;` to get the contents to the right. Much cleaner than using `floats`.

```css
.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgb(49, 48, 48);
  height: 115.8px;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li a {
  width: 80px;
  height: match-parent;
  background-color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#banner-img {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 105.8px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#banner-img:hover {
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

#banner-img:active {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  border-color: white;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--Main Navigation-->
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" id="banner-img" href="#home">
      </li>
      <li class="right-li">
        <a href="#me">Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="right-li">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the navbar height

```
.navbar {
    list-style: none;
    background: rgb(49, 48, 48);
    height: 115.8px;
}
```

or if you want to keep the navbar same size and

```
.right-li {
    float: right !important;
    height: 104px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line height for anchor elements

```css
li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
li a {
    width: 80px;
    line-height: 4.2;
    background-color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 24px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
li a:hover {
    background: #1075e9;
    /*border-radius: 50px;*/
    border-color: #1075e9;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
li a:active{
    background-color: #07274d;
    border-color: #07274d;
    transition: 0s;
}

.right-li{
    float: right !important;
}
.navbar {
    list-style: none;
    background: rgb(49, 48, 48);
    height: 115.8px;
}
#banner-img{
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 105.8px;
    padding: 4px; 
}
#banner-img:hover{
    background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#banner-img:active{
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    border-color: white;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mi-archivo-css.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test page</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>


    
    <header>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li>
                    <img src="logo.png" id="banner-img" href="#home">
                </li>
                <li class="right-li">
                    <a href="#me">Me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="right-li">
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </header>

    <body>    
        <!-- page content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution

```css
        li {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            height: 100%;

        }
        li a {
            line-height:110px; /* line height should be the same as the element's height*/
                    width: 80px;
                    height: 100%;
                    background-color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
                    font-family: Arial;
                    color: white;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    font-size: 24px;
                    padding: 0 24px; /* removed the padding from top and bottom to prevent the a element overflowing*/   
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-align: center;
                    display: inline-block;
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                    border-right: 1px solid black;
                    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        }
        li a:hover {
            background: #1075e9;
            /*border-radius: 50px;*/
            border-color: #1075e9;
            transition: all .4s ease 0s;
        }
        li a:active{
            background-color: #07274d;
            border-color: #07274d;
            transition: 0s;
        }

        .right-li{
            float: right !important;
        }
        .navbar {
            list-style: none;
            background: rgb(49, 48, 48);
            height: 115.8px;
        }
        #banner-img{
            /*border: 1px solid black;*/
            border-radius: 30px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 105.8px;
            padding: 4px; 
        }
        #banner-img:hover{
            background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
            transition: all .4s ease 0s;
        }
        #banner-img:active{
            background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
            border-color: white;
            transition: 0s;
        }
```

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
          <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mi-archivo-css.css">
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>Test page</title>
              <script src="script.js"></script>
          </head>



          <header>
              <!--Main Navigation-->
              <div class="navbar-container">
                  <ul class="navbar">
                      <li>
                          <img src="logo.png" id="banner-img" href="#home">
                      </li>
                      <li class="right-li">
                          <a href="#me">Me</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="right-li">
                          <a href="#about">About</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>      
          </header>

          <body>    
              <!-- page content -->
          </body>
      </html>
```

See Code Here you can edit also [See Code](https://jsfiddle.net/hdvnm39z/)